# the omission of so of so-that

Tags: omissibility

> In monarchical countries, the estates and the
>   greatest portion of the wealth are left to the first son, **that** the
>   vanity of the parent may be gratified by the thought that his name and
>   title are to descend to succeeding generations unimpaired.

I think the "**that**" is supposed to be "so that" considering the context. But Isn't it impossible to omit "so" of "so that"?

Comment: It would probably help if you mentioned that the source is a 19th century article by Andrew Carnegie, industrialist cum philosopher. The language is more than a bit dated and to a modern ear quite swollen.

Comment: One has to question the wisdom of trying to become familiar with the turns of phrase used in a text from 1889 written by Andrew Carnegie. It's not going to reflect today's English.

Comment: The omission of "so" in "so that" was fairly common for centuries, is all over the classics, and is used today occasionally for emphasis - or for laughs.

Comment: One question per Question please. I've edited out the secondary question. If you wish to ask it, please ask it separately.